# index.html runs ahead of Global.asax.cs or WebApiConfig.cs

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I was debugging why attribute routing not in effect and found an odd behaviour of WEB API project using VS 2017, that is

> any web page will run ahead of Global.asax.cs if it's "Set As Start
>   Page".

Here is how:

1. VS 2017, New project, C#, web, ASP.NET Web app.
2. Empty template, check WebAPI checkbox.
3. it now has Global.asax, WebApiConfig.cs inside of App_Start, place a break-point in either file.
4. Add an index.html file to the project, add a button to it, and set it as Start page.
5. F5, index.html runs, click on the button, everything runs as expected but **never** hits the breakpoint in WebApiConfig.cs.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="alert('hello');" />
</body>
</html>
```

This sample [proj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api#create-a-web-api-project) at MS site always hits the breakpoint: IF no Start page is set THEN always reach it before everything else, ELSE right after index.html is shown. Compared the .csproj file, only diff is it uses .NET framework 4.6 vs. 4.5.2. 
However, utilized 4.6 to create a new proj as aforementioned, result is the same.

Comment: And where is the problem? I assume index.html is served as a static file by IIS. It doesn't touch your API.

Comment: No it does, say an API call is invoked to test the method, it will never reach the supposed controller as WebApiConfig.cs never executes.

Comment: If you look into the MS example, they do an ajax call to the API when the document loads. That's what touches the API and triggers your breakpoints. Your index.html does nothing, so no need for the API to load...

Answer (score 0):

Although index.html is part of the project, starting it won't trigger the App_Start like I assumed, App_Start only triggered when a server-side .aspx starts or this project is hit by an Api request.